# sphinxsearch Laravel 5.2 "Nothing to publish for tag []."

Tags: php, search, laravel-5, sphinx

I have install sphinxsearch on my system and working fine for core php. Now i want to use it for laravel 5.2 . I have followed these step

```
1) install composer
2) 'providers' => array(
        'Scalia\SphinxSearch\SphinxSearchServiceProvider',
    )
3) 'aliases' => array(
      'SphinxSearch' => 'Scalia\SphinxSearch\SphinxSearchFacade',
    )
4)  php artisan config:clear

5)  php artisan config:publish scalia/sphinxsearch
    error [InvalidArgumentException]                
       Command "config:publish" is not defined.  
       Did you mean one of these?                
         vendor:publish                        
         config:clear                          
         config:cache 

 6) php artisan vendor:publish --provider=sngrl\SphinxSearch\SphinxSearchServiceProvider --force
    Nothing to publish for tag [].
```

How can i configure sphinxsearch in laravel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this in console

```
php artisan vendor:publish
```